# Wordpress plugin: How to depend on other plugins?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

I am writing a simple plugin for wordpress (actually a widget, packaged as a plugin, because reasons). I am using bootstrap to style the widget, because reasons. Now, the problem is that should I include bootstrap along the plugin or depend on another plugin (for example https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/). The first is easy, but not too nice way to do it. The second I actually have no idea going about. I have found some plugins (such as Plugin-Dependecies) that could be used for it, but I'd like to do it without the meta-plugin.

Is there a way for a plugin to depend on another plugin out-of-the-box? If yes, how should I do it?

Or if there is a better way to do the styling, what would that be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [WordPress Plugin Dependencies](https://github.com/xwp/wp-plugin-dependencies). It may help you.

Comment: That's what I found, but that isn't what I am looking for. What I need is a way for Wordpress to notify the user if they don't have the Bootstrap plugin installed or automagically install it along this one or something similar. The reason is that I can't install the dependency plugin on every single machine all the time.

Comment: @KalleAlanen I now understood, please check this solutions http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24717/how-would-you-require-and-automatically-download-dependent-plugins or try to use http://tgmpluginactivation.com/